# Install Kali Dual Boot w/ Windows 10 on Asus UX480F

Tags: linux, installation, kali-linux

I have an ASUS UX480F in which I installed Kali, however I ran into some troubles while installing, it couldn’t detect the SSD nor the unallocated space, I have managed to install it by changing SATA configuration in the BIOS to AHCI Mode, after the installation sometimes it freezes on the login screen and the touchpad works 2/5 times. I have been still using it even though there these problems. But I would like to know it there is any way to install my laptop drivers for Kali so I can get the most ou of it. Because I couldn’t find how to install all the needed drivers for my laptop on Kali. :(

Comment: https://kali.training/downloads/Kali-Linux-Revealed-1st-edition.pdf

Comment: It would not be wise to dual boot Kali and Windows unless you're encrypting the Kali install, as the exploits contained in Kali will be detected by Windows Defender.  Dual-booting, without encrypting the partition Kali is installed to, will also render the system insecure due to the exploits contained within Kali.

Comment: @JW0914, did that make sense in your mind? How will Windows detect anything on a partition it can't read from? Or anything exploited on an operating system that isnt running?

Comment: @Tim_Stewart Windows can read ext partitions... it's been able to for almost a decade.  Windows gained the ability to also write to ext partitions a few years back with Paragon's [Linux FS](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/linuxfs-windows/) (which is why I asked if it was going to be encrypted or not).  Generally speaking, it's simply not a good idea to have a partition full of malware on the same PC that you use daily or with Windows, which is why Kali is generally run on a separate PC or within a VM, but I'm not aware of anyone dual booting Kali and Windows.

Comment: Lol Full of malware? Not that I know of...  I don't run it alongside 8.1 or 10. It's running alongside 7. As far as I am aware since the rolling releases the ext file system is chmoded with the username/password by default. I'm still not understanding how you think programs **not** running in CPU/memory could be detected by any program running in windows. Can you provide any citable references for this? Not trying to be a jerk here, I have literally never heard of anything close to this. P.s you are now aware of one person that does! (Win/Kali/Ubuntu)